# How to separate session timeout value in web.xml JSF

Tags: jsf, timeout, web.xml

Hi i try to separate the timeout session value in JSF 2.0.

The duration has to be different in mobile pages and web pages.

In web.xml there is only one session-timeout element. How can i separate this value in mobile and web pages.

Thanks..

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>WebTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.webTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>webTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>MobileTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.MobileTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MobileTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Mobile/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout> --> ***this value***
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do it programmatically using [`HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29). You can do that in a servlet filter.